# How to read an excel file that is latest in a location and contains a particular word in its name

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to read an excel file that is latest in a location (folder/directory)  and contains a particular word in name.
For example a directory has following files:

```
file_apple_1jan.xlsx
file_apple_2jan.xlsx
file_apple_13jan.xlsx
file_mango_23jan.xlsx
```

I want to read latest excel file having "apple" in its name i.e. `file_apple_13jan.xlsx` from the directory without specifying explicitly preferrably using pandas. 

**Note:** I have used file names as per the dates they were created for ease here.

Comment: There was a similar question in vba on here recently - worth looking for.

Comment: You have not mentioned the 'similar question'. can you please do it @SolarMike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt anybody is going to write the code for you, but to get started here is an idea of how you can do it

1. Get all the filenames in the directory
2. Filter out that ones that don't have your keyword in them
3. Compare them using `os.path.getmtime(path)` to get the last modified date
4. Pick the one with the most recent last modified date